# Fixed position on rotate

Tags: java, android, rotation

I feel like this should be fairly simple, but I couldn't find anything online.

My question is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346864/rotating-uilabel-with-fixed-position), just for Android instead of iOS: I want to rotate UI elements while keeping their dimensions/position fixed on screen rotate. I realise I could create a second layout file for landscape, but I want to prevent a full reload of the activity on rotating when it involves downloading web content and processing it (takes a few seconds every time).

Comment: Thanks for the downvote and no feedback. *eyeroll*

Comment: Not downvoter but topic is covered by: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Ah, thankyou! That is actually really helpful for another issue I'm having. :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out myself using some help from this post: [Handling Screen Layout Changes In Android](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422431/Handling-screen-layout-changes-in-Android). Although their basic conclusion seems to be wrong that you can't keep a single layout and rotate in the manner I'm looking for?

Correct me if there's some fatal mistake I'm making, but the code I've used seems to work. The basic idea is to use a Linear Layout and change the orientation as the screen orientation changes:

```
//Manage screen rotation
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        LinearLayout readingsLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.readingsLinearLayout);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

            readingsLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        } else {

          readingsLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        }

    }
```